# Asus Memo Pad HD7 WiFi button is stuck at 'turning on WiFi...'

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean

My Asus MemoPad HD7 (ME173X) is unable to connect to WiFi. When I go to the WiFi settings, the on/off switch is in the off position. Moving it to on causes 'turning on WiFi...' to come up, but nothing more happens.

Under Advanced settings, neither a MAC nor IP address is available.

It's the same error as encountered in [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/Nn_pOgPC2Mk), except on a completely different piece of hardware. It's running Android 4.2.2 if that's any help.

Comment: Boot to the safe mode they try to turn on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

By just getting back to date from 10-12-2015 to 07-12-2015, in my case to be precise, everything is back to normal, and here I am sharing my facts to help all those who are facing this ridiculous problem.

P.S. had been searching throughout the net for the solution and found some interesting details, would love to share for others (if they can be of any help).

Factory formatting/soft or hard resetting won't work, so as the phone rebooting will also be not effective. Setting back the clock (manually) worked like a charm for me (my mobile Lenovo Vibe X, carrier Vodafone). This problem arose, in my case, when I updated certain apps 5 or 6 OTA on Google Play Store (mainly Google inbuilt ones).

---

For other users who suffer the same problem as I came to read through their posts: when they updated their handsets (for any updates, irrespective of any app), their WiFi settings got disturbed causing the WiFi to lock while initialising, not allowing the user to switch On or OFF, just displaying the screen Wi-Fi turning on/Scanning/Starting/Searching/etc.

A common solution suggested by many (which even I was going to try ~ if above hadn't work) was to solve it by deleting `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. It will reset all your saved networks. Have your phone rooted and delete the file through a root explorer or you can remove it via ADB (`adb shell rm -r /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I'm not sure). You may backup it before, then open it with a text reader to see your saved passwords.

On many forums, this was the common solution accepted as the only chance to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Unmounted the SIM card and SD card then tried, and it worked for me.

Comment: How are they related to Wi-Fi and what led you to do that?